# Determine if a Data instance is contiguous

Tags: swift

Let d be an instance of Data.  In earlier versions of Swift, I could test if it was contiguous in memory using code like

```
d.enumerateBytes{(pBuf: UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>, idx: Data.Index, flag: inout Bool) -> Void in
            if (pBuf.count == d.count) { print("Data is contiguous!") }
        }
```

However, in Swift 5 `enumerateBytes()` is deprecated, and I get a warning such as the following:

```
warning: 'enumerateBytes' is deprecated: use `regions` or `for-in` instead
```

I'm tempted to do something like

```
if d.regions.count == 1 { print("Contiguous!!!") }
```

Yet `regions` is of type `CollectionOfOne<Data>`, which by definition always contains one element.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the corelibs-foundation implementation, I don't see anything to suggest that `Data` supports non-contiguous storage. https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Data.swift#L117-L122 The apple implementation in macOS might differ, however.

Comment: @Alexander The macOS implementation is defined in the Swift overlay: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/013c4f1540c86a40507c9d3f6670aa60254d4540/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Data.swift.

Answer (score 10):

As of Swift 5, all `Data` values have contiguous storage, with the type conforming to the new [`ContiguousBytes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/contiguousbytes) protocol (implemented in [#20225](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20225)). As [@matt points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229364/determine-if-a-data-instance-is-contiguous#comment102833434_58229443), this change was [highlighted in a recent WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/723/?time=188):

> So from Swift 5 and onwards, we promise that struct Data is a contiguous buffer type.

Comment: It's officially documented in that it conforms to ContiguousBytes. And also because they said so: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/723/?time=121

Comment: @matt Ah thanks for the WWDC link! It would still be nice if it were mentioned in the doc comment for `Data` though.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback and links!

Comment: Hi man, can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712685/why-does-the-compiler-not-see-the-default-code-in-a-protocol

Comment: @Hamish  , happy new year!  there's a worthy question old chap: stackoverflow.com/questions/60062841

Comment: you too, @LeoDabus !